# Cocoa, Objective- C how correctly pass params from one window to another

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I'm really new in Cocoa/Obj-C programming.

I have fairly simple app (target platform Mac OSX 10.5 & 10.6), my background is C/C++ system programming.

I have a main Window with some text fields, buttons, properties etc. I setup outlets and actions (hopefully correctly). Additional window declared in another NIB is loaded upon one of the button clicks:

```
- (IBAction) openSettings: (id) sender
{
    ConfigurationWindowController * wc=[[ConfigurationWindowController alloc]     initWithWindowNibName:@"Configuration"];

    [wc showWindow:self];
 }
```

New window is being loaded and shows up.

I need to do following things :
1) pass some string params to the second ("child") window
2) receive this params back to the main window when second window is closing.

I'm not sure what is a correct way to do this in Cocoa.

@sergio :
Many thanks for your response! In my "child" window I store pointer to the main window nad before opening child window I pass some params:

```
ConfigurationWindowController * wc=[[ConfigurationWindowController alloc]     initWithWindowNibName:@"Configuration"];
mConfigWindow = wc;

[mConfigWindow setValuesToURL:@"some string here" storageParam:@"another string"     callerWindowPtr:self];
[wc showWindow:self];
```

This method is successfully called I see values stored in the "child" window class instance properties. However when I try to assign this values to the textfileds in the setValuesToURL method GUI elements are still null , I tried to assign stored strings in awakeFromNib method but here these properties are null! . Also value of self pointer is different - that means object created initWithWindowNibName and actual window with GUI are different. Obviously stored pointer to the "Main" window also is null when I try to pass back values. I suspect that problem is in NIB setup - really confusing to me.  I suspect is common misunderstanding of code/NIB relations, I tried different things but still cant get it work. Any guidance would be really useful.

```
-(void) setValuesToURL:(NSString*)strServiceURL  storageParam:(NSString*) strStorageURL     callerWindowPtr:(AppletAppDelegate *)_callerWindow
 {
     @try {
          NSLog(@"setValuesToURL was called with params %@ , %@" , strServiceURL     , strStorageURL);
        self.strDataStorageURL = strStorageURL;   
self.strServerURL = strServiceURL;
        self.callerWindow = _callerWindow;
[textServerURL setStringValue:[self strServerURL]];
    [textDataStorageURL setStringValue:[self strDataStorageURL] ];

        NSLog(@" after assigmnemnt  %@ , %@" , [self strDataStorageURL], [self      strServerURL]);

    }
     @catch (NSException * e) {
         NSLog(@"exception inf0 %@  " ,[[ e userInfo]      descriptionInStringsFileFormat]);
    }
    @finally {

    }

}
```

Good news - now string values are assigned to the NSTextField objects. I have a button on "child" window and on click I'm trying to call back parent pointer window methid :

```
- (IBAction) saveConfigurationSetings: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"saveConfigurationSetings: (id) sender");
        //close window and pass back URL strings 
    self.strServerURL =  [textServerURL stringValue]; 
    self.strDataStorageURL = [textDataStorageURL stringValue];
    [self.callerWindow passMeBackData: [textServerURL stringValue] strStorageURLParam:    [textDataStorageURL stringValue]];

    [self close];
```

}

Here callerWindow variable is null and passMeBackData fails . Here is declaration in h :

```
@interface ConfigurationWindowController : NSWindowController {
...
AppletAppDelegate *callerWindow; 
...
}


@property (assign) AppletAppDelegate * callerWindow;
```

in m file

```
@synthesize callerWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach isn't really how to do that; rather, it's how you've set up your setup.

A more appropriate flow for Objective-C/Cocoa would probably be to do the following:

1. Add the `ConfigurationWindowController` to MainMenu.xib; wire it to the menu item ApplicationMenu > Preferences (if memory serves, this should be possible to accomplish simply by implementing `- (IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender`, or something to that effect.)
2. Let the user change the settings, and write them to `NSUserDefaults` as they go. There's probably no need for a modal window or Apply/Cancel/OK buttons unless your settings are extremely complex or changing them is terribly expensive (computationally).
3. Either whenever a setting is changed, or the window closes, fire notifications to the application `NSNotificationCenter` that interested parties can observe. **Note:** Not all settings require notifications to be fired; only those that affect ongoing processes that cache the value of the setting.

There are other approaches as well, but this is probably the most easily extensible.

---

If the issue is that of opening the settings window on a specific pane; set the tag value of each control or menu item that opens the window appropriately; and check what pane you should open using `[sender tag]`.

---

If the issue is that you have an entire extremely specific settings window for each process in your application, that is probably a Bad Thing™.

Comment: Thanks a lot Williham. This specific design (Bad Thing™) is required by customer and I have neither will nor time to change this requirement. SO I have to create some custom settings window, actually 2 windows app...

Comment: @David: No time required; the phrase "That won't work." works wonders.

Comment: @David: But on a related note; using [sender tag], `NSUserDefaults` and notifications as required still solves your problem, and is almost certainly the way to go.